# Changing git history on public branch that was not used by other team members

Tags: git, gitlab, rebase

I created a branch for prototyping a new feature. After several iterations I am happy with the results and want to rebase it to master (or merge, that's not the problem).

Some additional information:

(1) I already published the branch. For example, I run

```
git push --set-upstream origin my-branch
```

(2) I am **sure** no one has been working that branch

(3) Other developers did do

```
git pull -r
```

to the **main** branch

Before doing the rebase to `master` (and then push master to upstream), I want to cleanup the git history of the branch. For example `squash`, `merge` and modify some commits.

I know that changing history can really cause pain to other developers, who worked on a branch. But taking into consideration point 2 and 3 from above, do I have a risk of problems changing commits and push upstream to an **unused branch by other developers**?

Comment: No problem with rewriting history of an unshared branch, no.

Comment: @Eyal Golan, my question is, are your trying to rebase the master (public branch) with your feature branch? or your feature branch with the master branch?

Answer (score 1):

> (2) I am sure no one has been working that branch

If none of the other developers are working on your feature branch you can change your commit history to your branch. Which doesn't cause conflicts unless they did a,

`git fetch` which updates new branches into local from origin.

Followed by `git checkout feautureA` which would create a `featureA` local branch.

If they did the above a don't have any changes on `featureA` branch, You can make history changes to your branch. But other developer need to reset only that feature branch using `git reset`

> (3) Other developers did do `git pull -r`

If they did `git pull -r` on `master` branch, git only updates `master` branch. It doesn't look into your `featureA` branch.

> Rebasing master

My suggestion is to never rebase the master until you know what you are performing.

`Merge` the feature branch into master, merge does not delete anything. It might perform a three way merge if you are branch off from a different branch like `XYZ`. which may look like.

```
Master — — — — —    
XYZ             \ — — —    
featureA               \ — — —
```

If you merge `feature A` into `master` `XYZ` commits may also be included into `master`.

If you want to rebase `feature branch` [Look here.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing)

Finally, if you believe you are only working on `featureA` branch. You can make your changes to history for that branch.

If you want to change the `master branch` history you need to communicate with other developers too and plan accordingly. As this would be the public branch other people work on usually.

Answer (score -1):

No worry ! No one wil have problem

You can do whatever you want in your branch and push it. Git will warn you and you have to use :

```
git push -f
```

When you will force push you rewrite branch other developper will see the changes the next time they will issue a git fetch/pull command.

Git will indicate that the branch was **force updated**

If they haven't checked out this branch they won't notice anything. If they have checkedout this branch without changes git pull -r should be sufficient.
Otherwise if they have change it dépends but shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thanks !
I know that in order to push we need to add the -f flag.
The question is , will it be pulled with the changes to the branch of another developer who *has not wrote anything* in that branch.

Comment: Answer updated : they shouldn't have anything to pull from this branch. Create a dummy branch and try if you have any doubt